# extracting specific column with certain condition on one column only

Tags: r

I have a data(in R) in below form,

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y44du.png)

A    B        C      D
x   alpha   sine     0
y   gama    cos      1
z   beta    tan      2

and I want to extract only column A & B where column D > 0.
i tried using data %>% filter(D > 0), which gives me last two rows where D>0 but it also gives me column c which i don't want.
how can i get only column A&B with condition applied on column D only.?

Data in text:

| A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| x | alpha | sine | 0 |
| y | gama | cos | 1 |
| z | beta | tan | 2 |

Comment: Next Post your data in text

Comment: `data %>% filter(D > 0) %>%select(A,B)`

Comment: thank you @onyambu but this gives me only column A& B, i also want to show column D.

Comment: @onyambu. yea i got it, just added select(A,B,D). thanks. alot for quick help.

Comment: Check the answer below. If you have many columns, you can use `select(-C)` to drop the columns you want. Consider upvoting /accepting the answer

Comment: thank you, @onyambu. similarly, if i want to select only top two from column to i can use slice function? but again slice function gives me all the columns but i need only column D.

Comment: just select the column you want, ie select(D)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
data %>% filter(D > 0) %>%select(A,B, D)
  A    B D
1 y gama 1
2 z beta 2
```

or even:

```
data %>% filter(D > 0) %>%select(-C)
  A    B D
1 y gama 1
2 z beta 2
```